# How to loop the output and write to excel

Tags: java, eclipse, loops

**This output what i try to do, Please help me everyone.**

number3 : 10;
linenumber : 200;
quantity : 200 / 10

**Example Output :-**

CLASS: SQUARE
DESIGN : RECTANGLE
START SERIAL : "Data Line 1"
END SERIAL : "Data Line 10"
NO OF LINE : 10
PER TOTAL: 1 / 20

CLASS: SQUARE
DESIGN : RECTANGLE
START SERIAL : "Data Line 11"
END SERIAL : "Data Line 20"
NO OF LINE : 10
PER TOTAL: 2 / 20

CLASS: SQUARE
DESIGN : RECTANGLE
START SERIAL : "Data Line 21"
END SERIAL : "Data Line 30"
NO OF LINE : 10
PER TOTAL: 3 / 20

```html
String text1 = TextReport1.getText();
                        String text2 = TextReport2.getText();

                        String text3 = TextReport3.getText();
                        int number3 = Integer.parseInt(text3);

                        String absolutePath = files.getAbsolutePath();
                        String filePath = absolutePath.substring(0,absolutePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
                        new File(filePath+"/Report").mkdir();
                        String date = format.format(new Date());
                        try {

                            String FPath = files.getAbsolutePath();
                            fr = new FileInputStream(FPath);
                            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fr));
                            String line = reader.readLine();      

                            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath + "/Report/"+ date + ".xls"));
                            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

                            int linenumber = 1;

                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                linenumber++;

                for(int i = 1; i<=linenumber;) {
                track1 = line.substring(0, 19);
                track2 = line.substring(0, 19);
                counter++;
                int start = 1 - number3 + number3;
                int end   = 1 + number3;

                if(counter == start)
                {
                   // do your code
                    System.out.println(track1);
                }
                if(counter == end)
                {
                   // do your code
                    System.out.println(track2);
                }


            int Quantity = (linenumber / number3);
            int i11 = 0;
            int i12 = 1;
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Loop Generator");
            HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) i11);

                                System.out.println(text1);
                                System.out.println(text2);
                                System.out.println(track1);
                                System.out.println(track2);
                                System.out.println("No." + number3);
                                System.out.println(i12 +  "/" +  Quantity);

                                row = sheet.createRow((short) i11+0);
                                row.createCell(0).setCellValue("CLASS");
                                row.createCell(1).setCellValue(" : ");
                                row.createCell(2).setCellValue(text1);
                                row = sheet.createRow((short) i11+1);
                                row.createCell(0).setCellValue("DESIGN ");
                                row.createCell(1).setCellValue(" : ");
                                row.createCell(2).setCellValue(text2);
                                row = sheet.createRow((short) i11+2);
                                row.createCell(0).setCellValue("SERIAL START ");
                                row.createCell(1).setCellValue(" : ");
                                row.createCell(2).setCellValue(track1);
                                row = sheet.createRow((short) i11+3);
                                row.createCell(0).setCellValue("SERIAL END ");
                                row.createCell(1).setCellValue(" : ");
                                row.createCell(2).setCellValue(track2);
                                row = sheet.createRow((short) i11+4);
                                row.createCell(0).setCellValue("NO OF LINE");
                                row.createCell(1).setCellValue(" : ");
                                row.createCell(2).setCellValue("NO :" number3);
                                row = sheet.createRow((short) i11+5);
                                row.createCell(0).setCellValue("PER TOTAL");
                                row.createCell(1).setCellValue(" : ");
                                row.createCell(2).setCellValue(i12 + "/" + Quantity);

                                sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
                                sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);
                                sheet.autoSizeColumn(2);

                                i11++;
                                i12++;

                        reader.close();
                        workbook.write(fos);
                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                        return;
                         }
                    }
                        }catch (IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you post a question, they belong to the site and its users. Even if it is no longer useful to you, it might be helpful to someone in the future. The answerers would have also put an effort in writing their answer, which would no longer be useful if you have removed the content from the post. Also, note that by posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: Please read Bhargav's comment above - do not vandalize your post.

Comment: Then don't down-vote my questions. If it useful why they down-vote?

Comment: i'm so sick of this website, alot of people think their soo brilliant. but no one ever answer my question. Many of my system i research by myself. All they know is down vote and act like god. If i'm mistake comment below not by down vote. i'm new here and im really unsatisfied with the people that think they good, but also like me start from below. I just want to say, this website is for learning, not show-off. If you know you teach, if you don't even know try to help.

Comment: and i already solve this question 2 and half months ago. BY MY SELF. Thanks for try and helping me before Flying Dutchman.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use Apache's library for reading comma separated values from a text-file, with 'comma' actually meaning a semi-colon character. It is also possible to specify a *different* separator character than ';', for example a space character '_'.

See the example code here.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;

public class ReadWriteProfile {
    public List<List<String>> readCSVFile(String filename, boolean bypassHeader) {
        List<List<String>> csvFile = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Reader in = new FileReader(filename);
            Iterable<CSVRecord> records = null;
            if (bypassHeader) {
                records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(in);
            } else {
                records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.parse(in);
            }
            for (CSVRecord record : records) {
                List<String> csvLine = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String field : record) {
                    csvLine.add(field);
                }
                csvFile.add(csvLine);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("readCSVFile: exception [{}]", e);
        }
        return csvFile;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i don't get that? My point is to Read Txt File and write to Excel.

Comment: And loop the number using looping / arraylist?
For example i put 10 in textbox and generate for Start -10 + 10 to get the first line then + 10 till the total number of line.
End 1 + 10 and loop till total number of line.

The output will be 
Start Line 1
End  Line 10
Start Line 11
end   Line 20 and soo on to total of data.

Comment: The flag 'EXCEL' just specifies an Excel-like csv-import of the Apache CSV-processor. You shouldn't pay notice to that. There are other options for this flag as well (INFORMIX_UNLOAD, MYSQL,POSTGRESQL_CSV,POSTGRESQL_TEXT), but the 'EXCEL' flag works fine. This idea of using the Apache CSV-reader is that it simplifies the Java code. You can also easily bypass a first-line header, or alter the separator character.